# how to make dir if it does not exists

Tags: ftp

I am trying to create a folder if it doesnot exists

here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="folder" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

here is my php code:

```
'<?php
$ftp_server="myserver";
$ftp_user_name="my username";
$ftp_user_pass="password";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

$dirname = $_POST ["folder"]; 

$filename = "/folder/$dirname/"; 

if (!file_exists($dirname))
{     mkdir($dirname, 0700); }
else{ echo'upload error'; ?>'
```

but it show this error message

```
Warning : mkdir() [function.mkdir ]: File exists in /home/a1268559/public_ html/profile/db.php
```

Comment: You probably want to check for $filename, not for $dirname

Comment: what is the right script? I also try it by if(!is_dir($filename))